# Having problems with theme slider

Tags: wordpress, image, slider, themes

Just uploaded a new theme. I'm working on it in the back end while I have a coming soon in the front end. My theme is perfect, but I have a problem with the slider images. I want them to adjust to the same size as the square by them so they look asymmetric. 
   I could show images on my issue. I tried the theme developers forum but for a change, got no help so far. Need to post my page. My deadline was 12AM EST and now is 3:50 EST. Please help!

Comment: Do you mean that your images should adjust their size according to the container.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying. When they show the theme, it has all images looking asymmetric, a perfect rectangle. It does not happens in reality for the slider. However, the images enlarge for other parts of the theme. And they enlarge many times more than their size perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should format your code like this:

```
<div id="container">
<img .../>
<img .../>
<img .../>
</div>

<style>
    #container{
    height:350px;
    width:650px;
    }

    #container img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
</style>
```

The properties which does all the work are `width:100%;` and `height:100%;`.

EDIT:

Add this code below your container-

```
#Container-ID img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Note: Replace **Container-ID** with the immediate container's id.

Comment: How do I apply this to the slider?

Comment: You just have to apply the width:100%; and height:100%; styles to the images in your slider.

Comment: The post are news, recent news, this means they will change all the time. I need something that would make the images in the slider to adjust to container. do you know how. to? BTW. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you know anything about CSS?

Comment: I know how to find code and enter it. I also know if it's a theme one has to do a CSS change and there's an attribute if that needs to be entered into the stylesheet of the child theme CSS.

Comment: So, you should find the id of the container and apply these two attributes to it.

Comment: Right now, I have been able to resize the container with some CSS provided by someone else to 500px. Which is what I was looking for. Now I need images that go into slider to fit container.

Comment: site is live so you could see aht I mean. Images are resizing for the posts at the bottom, same posts as slider for both show most recent news. However, the same images are not resizing for the slider. The site page is latinzonemagazine.com

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, but I mistakenly wrote that you have to apply the CSS to your container, instead, you have to apply it to the container's images. I am editing my answer and adding some more code, which you should paste below the CSS style of your container.

Comment: If you are having any problem with finding the immediate container's ID, then I can tell you that, but you'll have to tell me about which slider are you talking, because your home page is a bit confusing.

Comment: The first iamges on the left are the slider. Those are the only ones that change, those are the ones with the problem. Thing is, it says 100 for images already. Can't understand what's going on. Previous theme, which was free, gave me no issue.

Comment: Thanks, Solved with two plugins. :-) Thanks for your advise! Prakhar